# python 3: reading bytes from stdin pipe with readahead

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to read bytes. `sys.stdin` is opened in textmode, yet it has a buffer that can be used to read bytes: `sys.stdin.buffer`.

my problem is that when i pipe data into python i only seem to have 2 options if i want readahead, else i get a `io.UnsupportedOperation: File or stream is not seekable.`

1. reading buffered text from `sys.stdin`, decoding that text to bytes, and seeking back

   (`sys.stdin.read(1).decode(); sys.stdin.seek(-1, io.SEEK_CUR)`.

   unacceptable due to non-encodable bytes in the input stream.
2. using `peek` to get some bytes from the stdin’s buffer, slicing that to the appropriate number, and praying, as `peek` doesn’t guarantee anything: it may give less or more than you request…

   (`sys.stdin.buffer.peek(1)[:1]`)

   peek is really underdocumented and gives you a bunch of bytes that you have to performance-intensively slice.

btw. that error really only applies when piping: for `./myscript.py <somefile`, `sys.stdin.buffer` supports seeking. yet the `sys.stdin` is always the same hierarchy of objects:

```
$ cat testio.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from sys import stdin
print(stdin)
print(stdin.buffer)
print(stdin.buffer.raw)"
$ ./testio.py
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
<_io.BufferedReader name='<stdin>'>
<_io.FileIO name='<stdin>' mode='rb'>
$ ./testio.py <somefile
[the same as above]
$ echo hi | ./testio.py
[the same as above]
```

some initial ideas like wrapping the byte stream into a random access buffer fail with the same error as mentioned above: `BufferedRandom(sys.stdin.buffer).seek(0)` ⇒ `io.UnsupportedOperation…`

finally, for your convenience i present:

### Python’s io class hierarchy

```
IOBase
├RawIOBase
│└FileIO
├BufferedIOBase  (buffers a RawIOBase)
│├BufferedWriter┐ 
│├BufferedReader│
││        └─────┴BufferedRWPair
│├BufferedRandom (implements seeking)
│└BytesIO        (wraps a bytes)
└TextIOBase
 ├TextIOWrapper  (wraps a BufferedIOBase)
 └TextIO         (wraps a str)
```

and in case you forgot the question: how do i get the next byte from stdin without de/encoding anything, and without advancing the stream’s cursor?

Comment: I filed [python issue 16937](http://bugs.python.org/issue16937) because I was led to believe you could use `-u` to disable the buffering on `stdin`. No answer for you, as of yet.

Comment: Do you know what the buffer size of stdin that allows peek to work correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The exception doesn't come from Python, but from the operating system, which doesn't allow seeking on pipes. (If you redirect output from a regular pipe, it can be seeked, even though it's standard input.) This is why you get the error in one case and not in the other, even though the classes are the same.

The classic Python 2 solution for readahead would be to wrap the stream in your own stream implementation that implements readahead:

```
class Peeker(object):
    def __init__(self, fileobj):
        self.fileobj = fileobj
        self.buf = cStringIO.StringIO()

    def _append_to_buf(self, contents):
        oldpos = self.buf.tell()
        self.buf.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        self.buf.write(contents)
        self.buf.seek(oldpos)

    def peek(self, size):
        contents = self.fileobj.read(size)
        self._append_to_buf(contents)
        return contents

    def read(self, size=None):
        if size is None:
            return self.buf.read() + self.fileobj.read()
        contents = self.buf.read(size)
        if len(contents) < size:
            contents += self.fileobj.read(size - len(contents))
        return contents

    def readline(self):
        line = self.buf.readline()
        if not line.endswith('\n'):
            line += self.fileobj.readline()
        return line

sys.stdin = Peeker(sys.stdin)
```

In Python 3 supporting the full `sys.stdin` while peeking the undecoded stream is complicated—one would wrap `stdin.buffer` as shown above, then instantiate a new `TextIOWrapper` over your peekable stream, and install that `TextIOWrapper` as `sys.stdin`.

However, since you only need to peek at `sys.stdin.buffer`, the above code will work just fine, after changing `cStringIO.StringIO` to `io.BytesIO` and `'\n'` to `b'\n'`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, although i feel compelled to explain that i indeed correctly guessed that pipes aren’t seekable, and knew i needed to wrap `stdin.buffer` somehow. i thought there was a better way than implementing my own class to do that, but your answer seems to imply that there is no way to convince the vast array of builtin io-classes to do it. what i still don’t get, however, is why i need to wrap a a peekable stream in a TextIOWrapper if i want bytes. furthermore, i’m already able to call `stdin.buffer.peek`, as i said in the question, so i don’t get why you show that code… :/

Comment: You need bytes at that place, but the rest of the program also needs a working `sys.stdin`, if I understood you correctly. The point of the posted Python 2 code is that it implements reliable `peek` using `StringIO` since, as you pointed out, `BufferedReader.peek` can return less or more bytes than requested, and you're only allowed to call it once. The class in the answer does not have these limitations.

Comment: aah, now it clicked. nice! i don’t need a “working” stdin, because the program isn’t interactive and just parses bytes coming in through stdin. but it’s awesome that you answered with a solution for that, too. am i right that the real answer (python3) is just a `s/cStringIO.StringIO/io.BytesIO/` and a `s/'\n'/b\0/` from yours away?

Comment: Sure, if you don't need `stdin` to refer to your underlying peekable stream, then all you need is a wrapper over `stdin.buffer` as shown above, and then porting it to Python 3 should be as simple as changing `StringIO` to `BytesIO` and `'\n'` to `b'\n'`. Note that the wrapper only supports `read` and `readline`—you might also want to add `__iter__`.

Answer (score 3):

user4815162342's solution, while extremely useful, appears to have an issue in that it differs from the current behaviour of the io.BufferedReader peek method.

The builtin method will return the same data (starting from the current read position) for sequential peek() calls.

user4815162342's solution will return sequential chunks of data for each sequential peek call. This implies the user must wrap peek again to concatenate the output if they wish to use the same data more than once.

Here is the fix to return builtin behaviour:

```
def _buffered(self):
    oldpos = self.buf.tell()
    data = self.buf.read()
    self.buf.seek(oldpos)
    return data

def peek(self, size):
    buf = self._buffered()[:size]
    if len(buf) < size:
        contents = self.fileobj.read(size - len(buf))
        self._append_to_buf(contents)
        return self._buffered()
    return buf
```

[See the full version here](https://github.com/racitup/magicrescue-vmdk/blob/master/vmdk.py)

There are other optimisations that could be applied, e.g. removal of previously buffered data upon a read call that exhausts the buffer. The current implementation leaves any peeked data in the buffer, but that data is inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
import sys

ssb = sys.stdin.buffer.read(1)
if ssb == b'h':
    print(ssb+sys.stdin.buffer.read())
```

**Echo a string:**

```
a@fuhq:~$ echo 'hi' | python3 buf_test.py 
b'hi\n'
```

**Redirect a file:**

```
a@fuhq:~$ cat hi.text
hi
a@fuhq:~$ python3 buf_test.py   <  hi.text
b'hi\n'
```