# Peak at the sys.stdin before piping it to a subprocess (e.g. gzip)

Tags: python, subprocess

Data is coming in from the sys.stdin, but it could be either compressed (gzip) or uncompressed.

To solve this mystery, one could take a peek at the first 4 bytes of the stream. If they equal "\x1f\x8b\x08\x04" it's a gzip compressed file.

If the file is indeed compressed, one could decompress it with:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['pigz','--stdout','--decompress' , sys.stdin], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

However, if the first 4 bytes have already been consumed, pigz is going to reject this stream as not-a-gzip-compressed-file.

How can one read a few bytes from the sys.stdin without .read()'ing from it?

Alternatively, how can one send pigz the correct first 4 bytes and then the rest of the stream without getting into a deadlock?

EDIT2: I tried using the Peeker() class suggested in [python 3: reading bytes from stdin pipe with readahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283025/python-3-reading-bytes-from-stdin-pipe-with-readahead) , however it results in the error:

```
  File "./subprocess.py", line 1155, in _get_handles
    p2cread = stdin.fileno()
AttributeError: 'Peeker' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Perhaps i need to create a named pipe, write my four bytes to it, then somehow redirect the sys.stdin to that named pipe. Note that there could be many gigabytes of compressed data coming in, so it would have to be somewhat automatic as Popen(stdin=file_obj) is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python 3: reading bytes from stdin pipe with readahead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283025/python-3-reading-bytes-from-stdin-pipe-with-readahead)

Comment: i'm on py2 but i see that it could work on py3 with sys.stdin.buffer - that's good to know :)