# General way to interrupt scrolling text in console interface

Tags: python, console, keyboard, interrupt

i am trying to make a game in the console and want to have scrolling text. i want to be able to hit a key/type enter and skip the scrolling and print the rest. 
so far i tried using pygame (out of the picture due to having to have a display surface active), asyncio with sys.stdin.read(1)(blocked the run on cmd and didnt query user in async based ide's).

this was my latest attempts at this.

```
import asyncio,time,sys

global skip 
immutablesleep = 0.04
mutablesleep = [immutablesleep]

async def aprintl(string,sep="",end="\n",sleep=mutablesleep):
    global skip
    for letter in string+end:
        print(letter+sep,end="",flush=True)
        await asyncio.sleep(sleep[0])
    skip = True

async def break_print():
    global skip
    while not skip:
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        if len(ch)>0:
            mutablesleep[0]=0
            skip = True
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)    


def printl(*args):
    global skip
    skip = False
    mutablesleep[0] = immutablesleep
    asyncio.gather(aprintl(*args),break_print())
```

keep in mind when suggesting modules that i want both os system independant code, and something that can be easly hooked into when freezing modules into exe.

### Update:

currently this functions fairly well in terms of interrupting the slow print, but two issues persist:
1:
the interruption by pressing enter is cutting through the printed line, making it unreadable
2:
thread is still waiting for enter even after the print finished.

```
async def break_print():
    global skip, ch
    thread = Thread(target=t)
    thread.start()
    thread.join(timeout=0.1)
    while not skip:
        if len(ch) > 0:
            mutablesleep[0]=0
            skip = True
            ch = ''
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)


def t():
    """Needed to read from stdin async"""
    global ch
    ch = sys.stdin.readline()
```

Comment: "Didn't work" is kind of a generic description. Please describe what exactly happened, in response to an exact sequence of events you triggered.

Comment: Stdin read(1) blocks the thread on cmd but on an ide it is returned empty no matter the letter pressed. In any case the blocking property of it on cmd makes it a bit useless for my purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I believe your problem has to do with the last line</s>

```py
asyncio.gather(aprintl(*args),break_print())
```

<s>Looking at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather), the function signature looks like this: `awaitable asyncio.gather(*aws, loop=None, return_exceptions=False)`. The `.gather` call is likely not working as expected because you are not passing a list of callables, you're instead passing `aprintl(*args)` to `*aws` and `break_print()` is being passed to the `loop` argument</s>

<s>Change the line to the below, and see if it works as you're expecting.</s>

```py
asyncio.gather([aprintl(*args),break_print()])
```

## Update

I got your code to work, with some caveats

```py
import asyncio
import sys
from threading import Thread

global skip
ch = ''
immutablesleep = 0.04
mutablesleep = [immutablesleep]


async def aprintl(string,sep="",end="\n",sleep=mutablesleep):
    global skip
    for letter in string+[end]:
        if not skip:
            print(letter+sep,end="",flush=True)
            await asyncio.sleep(sleep[0])
    skip = True


async def break_print():
    global skip, ch

    while not skip:
        thread = Thread(target=t)
        thread.start()
        thread.join(timeout=.1)

        if len(ch) > 0:
            mutablesleep[0]=0
            skip = True
            ch = ''
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)


def t():
    """Needed to read from stdin async"""
    global ch
    ch = sys.stdin.readline()


async def printl(*args):
    global skip
    skip = False
    mutablesleep[0] = immutablesleep
    await asyncio.gather(aprintl(*args), break_print())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = ['asdf ', 'asdf']*5000
    asyncio.run(printl(x))
```

**What was changed**

- Added `t()` which runs in a Thread for .1 seconds every time `break_print` runs -- this was required as I believe the reason your initial code isn't running is because it's hanging at the `sys.stdin.read(1)` line
- Run `printl()` via `asyncio.run()`
- Added an `if not skip:` check in `aprintl()`, otherwise it will print the entire input once skipped

**Caveats**

- You *must* hit enter to stop the printout -- even with `.read()` you *must* hit enter. I use `readline()` because it will return any characters input before the enter key is hit (meaning, you could check to make sure the user input some character before hitting enter: `len(ch.strip() > 0): do ...`
- The script doesn't exit even after `skip == True` -- this is likely because `break_print()` doesn't exit when `skip == True`, it will simply continue to loop.

I realize this may not work in your use case, but I hope it at least gives you some ideas.

Comment: That is actually functioning fine. The * in *aws means all positional arguments are taken in as a tuple, and they both run. You must use loop as keyword. They can both print statements at the same time if needed, i just want to be able to interrupt it midway(without alt+c because that would break other parts)

Comment: @daniel.f - you are correct. what a silly mistake on my part. Thanks for the clarification. I've updated my answer with a working example that may be what you're looking for.

Comment: I like the approach, but at the moment the more threads start, the more enters i have to press to go on with the rest of the code. i am trying to check if there is a way to force timeout on input, and at the same time to see if there is a way to hide the entered input so it will not disrupt the text.

Comment: This is a bit more invovled, but you can create a class that you can set to `sys.stdin` -- ie. `sys.stdin = Peaker()`. See [this SO post about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14292897/7253453). It may be possible to have this class handle flag setting, as well as capturing user input without printing it to stdout

Comment: Thanks. in the end i think this is too much effort for a small mechanic in a game. i settled on catching the interrupt and reprint the entire text just fast. much less technical. ill manage whatever printed before in a kwarg so it wont erase it.  it has more dev side management, but it is less work overall.  the threading did help though.

Comment: Sorry we couldn't find a more elegant solution.

Comment: That is fine. while elegant is nice, simple and working is better ;)